# CASE Logic on Text to Provide Number Results In Converting Data Type Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

This code doesn't work in a SQL Server query, is there a way around this?

```
CASE WHEN table1.Code = 'Food' THEN table1.Amount Else NULL END as "Fee"
```

I get this error:

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1
>   Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

I am assuming its because I'm searching on a text field and then grabbing a numeric field in that same table, but this seems pretty straight forward. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: Hi JustAnotherFaceInTheCode. Can you give use the full query? I find it hard to see the problem with just this portion of the script

Comment: That did it, so weird, I don't remember ever having to do this in the past, thanks for the solution AlwaysLearning.  Oracle is so much easier to program out of.

Comment: If it's that expression that's erroring, then there's only one reason; `Code` is a numerical data type, and as such you can't convert the value `'food'` to the data type. Why are you trying to check if a number had the value `'food'` anyway?

Comment: Try to learn to avoid double-quotes around aliases as well. AS [Fee] would be better, if quoting is needed at all.

Comment: Larnu - The table can have hundreds of different entries of codes with dollar amounts associated but the tables are not normalized where I can just take the value I need.  I'm just needing an IF statement basically.

Comment: But if `Code` is a numerical data type it can **never** have the value `'food'`; I shouldn't need to tell you this but `'food'` isn't a number and that's why you're getting the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CASE WHEN table1.Code = 'Food' THEN cast(table1.Amount as varchar(8)) Else '0' END as "Fee"
```

Check table1.Code data type.

table1.Code must be a Character/String not a Numeric datatype.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT try_cast(Amount AS FLOAT) Fee
FROM table1
WHERE try_cast(Amount AS FLOAT) IS NULL;
```

You can use `try_cast` to check which rows are failed.